# Possible Shiny bug - multiple updateRadioButtons don't work?

Tags: r, shiny

I have 3 sets of radio buttons and I want to update/ reset them under certain conditions:

```
plotChoices <- c(
    "Line Graph" = "line",
    "Scatter Plot" = "scatter"
)
```

So if "line" is not selected all together at these 3 sets, then reset plot2's and plot2's:

```
observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    if (input$plot1 == 'line' &&
        (!is.null(input$plot2) && input$plot2 == 'line') &&
        (!is.null(input$plot3) && input$plot3 == 'line')
    ) return ()
    updateRadioButtons(
        session,
        "plot2",
        label = "Analyze Plot2 data:",
        choices = plotChoices,
        selected = character(0),
        inline = FALSE
    )
    updateRadioButtons(
        session,
        "plot3",
        label = "Analyze Plot3 data:",
        choices = plotChoices,
        selected = character(0),
        inline = FALSE
    )
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "plot2")
})
```

But it does not work at all. It only reset plot2 but not plot3.

Any ideas? Is it a bug in Shiny?

Comment: Are you using the right ID? It would be easier to help if you had a more complete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we could run and test to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: @MrFlick `Are you using the right ID?` Yes I am sure they all are correct.

Comment: And you are only calling `session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "plot2")` for "plot2"?

Comment: the problem seems to be coming from `selected = character(0),`

Comment: `And you are only calling session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "plot2") for "plot2"? ` it should be for plot3 as well. but it has no difference if I add that same line for plot3.

Comment: If the problem is `character(0)` have you tried replacing it with `NULL`. This is what the default is set to anyway for `updateRadioButtons()`

Comment: @MikeH. it does not work by replacing it with `NULL`. the first item in the radio button list still selected.

Comment: Radio buttons always need something selected. Try it with a `checkboxGroupInput` instead?

Comment: @MikeH. I have tried `checkboxGroupInput` before. any good examples?

Comment: @MikeH. i found the example. thanks. i think Shiny is really a bad framework after a few years using it. it is extremely inflexible.